# WebDriver findElement by xPath, no TIMEOUT if element is not found, screen just hang there.

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I face some issue whereby the test just hang there (Browser open and not able to proceed next test) due to my test statement not able to find the element.

My TestStatemet like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='AID' and contains(@value,'sampleDataThatwillNotFound')]"));
```

The test hang only when find by XPATH, no issue when find by NAME/ID. I had set the timeout to 60 seconds, after the 60 seconds, it still hang.

Anyone out there facing this issue before? or Anyone got any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What driver? What version of that driver? What version of that browser? What version of Selenium? What OS? What HTML?

Comment: WebDriver (selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0), tested on FF, version 17.0.2, Win7 Professional 64Bit.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem: you don't get the "NoSuchElement" Exception?

Comment: Hi Alex, i didn't get any exception. The FF Browser just hanging there. Is anyone out there facing this kind of issue as well?

Comment: exact same issue for me as well. Not just xpath, even By.className also stuck similarly for me even after setting implicit timeout. I'm using chromedriver and 2.29 version of selenium webdriver.

Comment: Hi Buddha, had u found ur solution already?

Comment: What a huge tar pit selenium webdriver is :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had try some answer above, but still having same issues.. i switch back to old firefox version 17.0.3 .... everything just solve.. abit funny.. those that facing the same issue you can try at FF Version 17.0.3

Answer (score 5):

Well, I had the same problem and found this in **webdriver api doc**:
`findElement` should not be used to look for non-present elements, use `findElements(By)` and assert zero length response instead.

So I use something like

```
List<WebElement> found = driver.findElements(By.id("elementid"));
if (found.size() > 0) 
{
    // get the 1st element
} else {
    // time out
}
```

to resolve this issue. And implicit timeout works fine with `findElements` in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue after upgrading Firefox (25 to 26) and Selenium (2.37.1 to 2.39.0 driver + server). No Exception thrown, hang forever, etc. It got "solved" by removing the `implicitlyWait` declaration. Not a real solution but good enough in my case.

Answer (score 0):

try this one locator

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='AID'][contains(@value,'sampleDataThatwillNotFound')]"));
```

Comment: Hi, i just tried, but still cant.. i will try more again, and update here ;D

Comment: have you verified xpath in firebug?

Comment: Hi Eugene, i sure that the xPath is correct, as i put in the correct value it is able to RUN.

Answer (score 0):

I got some feedback from darrell from Google Groups, and i agree with him, below is his feedback:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/Vt0DuQHOAg8

***I haven't seen these locators hanging but anything is possible. 
Generally, if the DOM is large and/or complex a combination locator 
(one with contains plus an and) could make it really slow. My general 
experience has been the more complex the locator the long it takes. 
The longer it takes the more likely you will see a 
NoSuchElementException. It could be that something else you are doing 
is causing a second problem, i.e. the hanging. 
An and statement is multipling. So @name='AID' is relatively fast. 
There is no substring checking. It either matches or it does not. So 
this locator will run in order n, where n is the number of input tags. 
A locator like contains(@value, 'someString') will have to scan each 
tag for each attribute for a match to every possible substring. If the 
contains() is implemented well it could be a little faster than brute 
force but the type of data in the DOM will determine how long this 
search will take. It will definitely be slow. 
Now if you take the contains() search (relative slow) and the exact 
match (relatively fast) then look for the AND of the two matches, you 
are multiplying them. Two exact matches are going to be order n times 
order n (or n squared). This is not good. An exact match times a 
contains is REALLY bad. Depending on the DOM it could be order n 
cubed. This means if n takes 10 seconds, n cubed is 10 * 10 * 10 
seconds (1000 seconds or over 16 minutes). If the DOM causes things to 
be even worse you could be looking at exact match is seconds and 
combination is hours. 
Darrell***

So to solve this issue, i think it is time to enforce the development team to apply to the common development practise to put in unique id for every element/control. So that the test automation script can directly perform any verification/input thru ID, instead of xPath.