# InternetExplorerDriver hangs after click() is called on a button

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm bound to using IE for a certain test and all goes well until I try to press a button, which generates a report.

```
WebElement btn=driver.findElement(....);//gets the button
btn.click(); // this does indeed click the button
println("Random message") //<-it doesn't get to this
```

What I can see in the source is that the button has an onClick going for a lot of lines beginning with :

```
return document.getElementById(...[LOTS OF elements and attributes....validation]....)
```

So, given the scarce amount of information I am able to provide, did anyone encounter this before? There are no exceptions or any kind of hints being provided during runtime.

Comment: can you drop your html ? and can you exmplain more the fact that "the button has an onClick going for a lot of lines beginning with" ?

Comment: I'm saying that the button has an onclick method applied which does validation on Select fields across the form. As for html source, I can't post any part of it.

Comment: And you don't have time out, ain't ?

Comment: I tried all kinds of variations of implicitlyWait and pageLoadTimeout and also tried with specific WebDriverWait with ExpectedCondition before.

Comment: i've seen the "same" case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454866/webdriver-findelement-by-xpath-no-timeout-if-element-is-not-found-screen-just) take a look

Comment: @e1che I'll take a look, maybe it's because I'm using xpath in IE driver